# Is there way a to find if consecutive rows have the same value in Google Sheets and produce a statement based on those values? Find 3 zeros in a row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

[image]

I have tried to use =IF(AND(ARRAYFORMULA(I4={J4:AB4})),"stop","keep") but I can only choose the first value in the formula. For example, if Trade 4 turns to zero then I should be able to stop at Trade 4 and don't enter any value at Trade 5. I want to be able to at any point in the series determine if there are 3 zeros in a row and produce a string to say "stop" in the H column. Any advice?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in cell `H3`:

```
=if( 
  regexmatch(textjoin("", true, I3:3), "000"), 
  "Stop", 
  "Continue" 
)
```

Comment: it only continues to produce "Continue". It doesn't produce "stop" with the three consecutive zeros from cells N3:P3. @Doubleunary

Comment: The formula processes all of row 3, regardless of how many columns you add. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to adjust your formula to instead of using column 3 with titles and instead I used column where the values are:                                                                             
  =if( 
  regexmatch(textjoin("", true, I4:4), "000"), 
  "Stop", 
  "Continue" 
)
@Doubleunary